# How do I do natural sorting with a MySQL query where the thing I want sort by starts with a letter?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have the following MySQL:

```
SELECT scott, title FROM stampitemdetails WHERE scott REGEXP '^RW[0-9]+$' ORDER BY CAST(scott AS UNSIGNED), scott;
```

The problem is that this query is bringing back my results ordered like this:

```
RW1
RW10
RW11
RW2
```

When they should be like this:

```
RW1
RW2
RW10
RW11
```

How do I do natural sorting when my value starts with a character and ends with a number?

What if the length of the `RW` can fluctuate.... meaning it could be `S`, or `REN`, or some other characters of unknown length before the number? Keep that in mind.

By the way, I have the RegEx in the query because in my PHP code the `RW` can be replaced with other characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract the numerical part

```
  SELECT scott, title 
  FROM stampitemdetails 
  WHERE scott REGEXP '^RW[0-9]+$' 
  ORDER BY substr(scott, 1,2),  CAST(substr(scott, 3, 100)  AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: What if the length of the `RW` can fluctuate.... meaning it could be `S`, or `REN`, or some other characters of unknown length before the number?

Comment: This is a suggestion .. but you can use vars  based  ond the lenght you are using  for seach  so (scott, 1,2)  became  (scott, 1,length(your_str)  ) ..

Answer (score 0):

I have a real hack to offer you.

```
 ORDER BY 0+REVERSE(CAST(0+REVERSE(scott) AS CHAR))
```

What does this do?

1. starting with your data for example `RW123` ...
2. it reverses the order of the characters in this column of yours.  `321WR`
3. by adding 0 to that, it converts it to a number, which scrubs off the now-trailing letters.   `321`
4. it casts that number back to a character string.  `321`
5. it reverses that character string again `123`
6. by adding 0 to that character string it casts it again as a number.  `123`
7. it orders by that number (as a number, not a character string).

Told you it's a hack.

If you have a bunch of different letter prefixes and you want to order with those lexically and then with the numbers, you need this pattern.

```
       ORDER BY letters, numbers
```

To get the first part of that, you'll have to extract just the letters.

You can do that with

```
      REPLACE(scott,REVERSE(CAST(0+REVERSE(scott) AS CHAR)),'')
```

This replaces the numbers in your character string with nothing.  So now you need

```
     ORDER BY REPLACE(scott,REVERSE(CAST(0+REVERSE(scott) AS CHAR)),''),
              0+REVERSE(CAST(0+REVERSE(scott) AS CHAR))
```

Please *please* write a comment explaining this to your successor if you use it in code.